# WPF C# Send Value in Another Form And Bind Data in Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Hello i have one questions,i'm sending data with parameters from Form1 to Form2:

```
DataRowView rowview = datagrid_system.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(rowview.Row[0]);
       Form2 be = new Form2(id);
```

And in Form2 Load I'm calling 1 function to binding from database all id in ComboBox1, but this is my problem for example in Form1 have ids(1,2,3,4,5) the user is selected id=3 and this id=3 is sending in Form2 I want to do this id=3 displaying in first combobox and other data displaying after this.
Example:

3->First data in combobox, other data is binding by function Form2 Load

1,2,4,5

In Form2 Load Binding Function:

```
 public void BindComboBox(ComboBox cmb_system)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Connection.DB);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select id FROM db_systems", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "db_systems");
        cmb_system.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        cmb_system.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the row order in your Table or add a column to sort the table or perhaps transform it to another datastructure (list for example).

Comment: Thanks for reply @BennoDual,but I thought this:Form1 is send data id=3(example) and in Form2 how to search in  combobox  what is index id "id=3" ,if is index id=3 im trying this cmb_system.SelectedIndex=3;